# Cereal Alpha and Beta Amylase temperature range and reaction rate

Tags: enzymes, temperature

This question is motivated by a practical application in bread making.
While it is well known which are the optimal (highest reaction rate) temperatures for both alpha and beta amylase, I am not able to find any precise information concerning reaction rate as a function of temperature.

1. How does alpha and beta amylase activity change when temperature decreases?
2. At which temperatures does their activity stop?